# How do I get my formula to execute within my function?

Tags: python, function

I am receiving a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'.

I am new to programming so my experience and exposure is very minimual. I am trying to execute my windchill formula within my function, but seem to be receiving an error can anyone provide any hints or advice as to where I'm going wrong?

## Function get_wind

1. This function will input a wind speed from the user
2. and return the wind speed to the calling function
3. Input to function: None
4. Output from function: returns the wind speed input by the user

```py
def WindChill(temp,wind):
    value_1=temp
    value_2=wind
    value_3=(35.74+0.625*temp-35.75*wind**0.16+0.4275*temp*wind**0.16)
    temp=get_temp
    wind=get_wind
    return value_3

WindChill()
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'function'.`

Comment: what does     ```temp=get_temp``` and
    ```wind=get_wind``` do?

Comment: temp=get_temp and wind=get_wind are two other functions with user input values.

Comment: def get_temp():
    value_1=float(input('enter temperature'))
    return value_1
def get_wind():
    value_2=float(input('enter wind speed'))
    return value_2

Answer (score 0):

First, Python is *very* picky about indentation.  It basically defines what's in the function and what isn't.  From the above code It looks like you are calling the function inside the function.  Not sure if that is a copy/paste error or not but just FYI.

Second, as written, you have to pass the parameters into the function. You define the function as

```
def WindChill(temp, wind):
```

If you want the function to call get_temp and get_wind, then you don't need any parameters.

Updated: I took the liberty of copying your code into my editor and changing it slightly and it runs without errors.  I assume get_temp and get_wind read some value from a sensor or something.  So I hard coded them in the example.

```
def get_temp():
    result = input("Enter the temp: ")
    return result

def get_wind():
    result = input("Enter the wind speed: ")
    return result

def WindChill():
    temp = get_temp()
    wind = get_wind()
    value_3 = (35.74 + 0.625 * temp - 35.75 * wind ** 0.16 + 0.4275 * temp * wind ** 0.16)
    return value_3


def main():
    print("%.2f" % WindChill())

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Result is:

```
Enter the temp: 70
Enter the wind speed: 12
70.82
```

I limited it to 2 decimals cause it was ugly.  Not necessary just me being me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430385/dr-code-monkey   makes sense but I have two other functions named "get_temp" and get_wind" the values are supposed to be user inputs and then calculate windchill. here I see you gave the paremeters a constant value. how do I code this function to take user input values to calculate?

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't get that from the example.  Edited my answer.

Comment: how exactly would I call it in the "main()" function? here's what I have so far

Comment: def main():
    print_table()
    for index in range(5):
        print("\n")
        temp=get_temp()
        wind=get_wind()
        WindChill(35.74+0.625*temp-35.75*wind**0.16+0.4275*temp*wind**0.16)
        printWindChill(WindChill,temp,wind)

Comment: You don't really need a main function in python.  just run python "myfile".py  But if you really want one You can do `if__name__== "__main__":  main()`

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no reason for the parentheses.
2. You have to be very precise with your indents. The function call after your return statement can't be indented or Python will think it is part of the function.
3. The function call needs two arguments because your function has two parameters.

Try the following:

```py
def WindChill(temp, wind):
    return 35.74 + 0.625 * temp - 35.75 * wind ** 0.16 + 0.4275 * temp * wind ** 0.16


print(WindChill(24, 4))
```

> 18.98200054

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an issue with this code if it's formatted this way:

```
def WindChill(temp,wind): 
    value_1=temp 
    value_2=wind 
    value_3=(35.74+0.625*temp-35.75*wind**0.16+0.4275*temp*wind**0.16) 
    #temp=get_temp 
    #wind=get_wind 
    return value_3 
WindChill(94.3,33.2)
```

Comment: makes sense but I have two other functions named "get_temp" and get_wind" the values are supposed to be user inputs and then calculate windchill. here I see you gave the paremeters a constant value. how do I code this function to take user input values to calculate?